# Site Accessibility in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, web, accessibility

We had done(completed) a website in **drupal 6.20.** At the time of development we have not consider site accessibility!. Now we wanted to meet all accessibille standerds for our site for all type of users in web.

Is there any module or method to do this ? please share your opinion on this topic and guide me to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet or program that can make your site accessible in five easy steps. For a general intro to web accessibility see [this link](http://webaim.org/intro/)
For a list of Drupal modules that can help with accessibility look at [this wiki page](http://groups.drupal.org/node/85199) For a tool that can scan web pages for possible accessibility issues check out [Wave](http://wave.webaim.org/)

Comment: well I got this link from web [link](http://fae.cita.uiuc.edu/) maybe its helpfull to someone...